# Scripting Sysinternals Process Explorer

Tags: shell, process, command, verification, sysinternals

So the situation is pretty simple.  We have remote management solution LabTech.  It has a process view tab, however, what im really looking for is a way to run the process signature verification that is available in Sysinternals Process Explorer.  The scripting options are minimal with Process Explorer so im open to other options.  Even a different app that I can run commandline and dump signature verification to a log file.